# How can i solve this Erorr Could not open SSL LIbray

Tags: freepascal, lazarus, ohhttpstubs

Hey i am getting this error if i start my program. I am using Lazarus as plattform.
I am trying to get the source code of the site with following code:

```
uses Classes, SysUtils, FileUtil, Forms, Controls, Graphics, Dialogs, StdCtrls,
  fphttpclient,openssl,fpopenssl,Buttons;   

s := TFPCustomHTTPClient.SimpleGet('https://freepascal.org');
```

In the end my programm should show me the source code in the programm.
Thanks for your help:)

[image]

Comment: do you have the openssl libraries present in your application directory as outlined in [the documentation](https://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/fphttpclient)?

Comment: What does this have to do with HTML and CSS?

Answer (score 1):

Download OpenSSL binaries and copy the DLLs in your executable folder or somewhere on the path. Pay attention that there are a lot of OpenSSL versions and they are not always interchangeables! Be sure to download the correct one.

If you have already the OpenSSL installed, then use a tool like [ProcessMonitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to spy on your own application to find out which DLL it tries to open and where it expect the DLL to be.

Comment: Hey i am really new in this type of coding how can i find out which OpenSSL interchangeableare?

Comment: Usually they are not backward compatible. So you'd better find out which version your application needs and install that one. I can't answer you because I'm using Delphi but you should find the information in Lazarus ecosystem. Install any version, if it is not the correct one, your application will not show the same error but usually crash with some access violation.